# Attachment is going to Gmail but not other mailboxes

Tags: php, email

These are the headers which I am using to send email with an attachment, however the attachment only gets through to Gmail. For all other mailboxes I tried, only the message content arrives, without the attachment.

```
     # Define the main headers
     $header = "From:$from_email1\r\n";
     $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
     $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; ";
     $header .= "boundary=$num\r\n";
     $header .= "--$num\r\n";

     # Define the message section
     $header .= "Content-Type: text/html\r\n";
     $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding:8bit\r\n\n";
     $header .= "$message1\r\n";
     $header .= "--$num\r\n";

     # Define the attachment section
     $header .= "Content-Type:  multipart/mixed; ";
     $header .= "name=\"test.txt\"\r\n";
     $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64\r\n";
     $header .= "Content-Disposition:attachment; ";
     $header .= "filename=\"$cv_view12\"\r\n\n";
     $header .= "$encoded_content\r\n";
     $header .= "--$num--";

     # Send email now

     $retval = mail ( $to, $subject1, $message1, $header );
```

Comment: I don't see recipients list and corresponding code here

Comment: you should check the source of the mail that arrived in the mailbox, compare that to gmail and see if there are any differences, and inspect it closely (you might think you have setup the mail correctly, but in the source you can see any anomalities more quickly)

Comment: We are getting the remaining variables in the mail function from  the database.

Answer (score 0):

What's the size of the attachment?

[Gmail has a 25mb attachment limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_attachment#Size_limits), which is a lot larger than many email providers.

Now, I'd expect you'd get a bounce-back message telling you that the attachment is too big if this is the case, but if the email address you're using for "From" is not valid, this wouldn't bounce back to anywhere you could see.

I'd start by setting a valid "From" address and see if you get any messages back as to why.

I also highly recommend Swift Mailer:
http://swiftmailer.org/

Which takes a lot of the complexities out of sending mail, and may automatically fix a small typo in manually creating a mail message. There is also a lot of advanced functionality built-in which makes life much easier.

Comment: OP says: "For all other mailboxes I tried, **only the message content arrives**, without the attachment.". So there will be no bounce message. Although using swiftmailer (or any other library) will definitely help.